# How to reduce given list by using Lambda expression .reduce() method

Tags: java, filter, lambda, java-8, reduce

```
List<Integer> integers = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10);
integers.stream().filter((integer) -> integer % 2 == 0).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

As shown above `integers` is a List, from which we need to filter only even numbers. I can achieve by using `.filter()` method. But, is there any possibility to achieve the same with `.reduce()` method. Hope, `.reduce()` method filtered out all the other elements by performing given BynaryOperation and return reduced list.

If my understanding is not correct on `.reduce()` method, please let me know what exactly this method do.

Comment: I don't get it. What's your requirement? Do you want to reduce all the even numbers in the `List`? You can chain `filter` and `reduce` as `filter` is an intermediate operation.

Comment: Yes, it is somehow possible to do that, but `reduce` is the wrong tool for that! Use `filter` as you already suggest.

Comment: I just want to remove all odd numbers from the list and return even numbers list with the help of reduce() method.

Comment: @ParameshKorrakuti You're trying to use an hammer when a screwdriver is necessary. Don't make things more difficult and potentially wrong (ex: when turning your stream in parallel). Just use `filter` and `collect`...

Comment: May I ask what benefits you expect by choosing `reduce` over `collect`? Or is it just a mental exercise?

Comment: @AlexisC, by seeing implementation given by  kocko's with reduce(), feel its better to use filter() only. Initially I feel reduce() will do better than filter() to reduce elements from list.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your understanding of reduction is wrong. `reduce` will apply a function on all elements repeatedly to get *one single result*.

You seem to think of reduce like doing

```
1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10
│  │  │  │  │  │  │  │
└op┘  └op┘  └op┘  └op┘
  │     │     │     │
    result list
```

whereas, in fact, it does

```
1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10
│  │  │  │  │  │  │  │
└op┘  └op┘  └op┘  └op┘
  │    │      │    │
  └─op─┘      └─op─┘
     │          │
     └────op────┘
           │
   final result value
```

Though, this is a conceptional view, the exact order of operations is unspecified. A sequential execution will be like `(((1 op 2) op 3) op 4)…` while a parallel execution will be a mixture of an execution like the tree above and partial sequential execution(s).

---

You can abuse `reduce` to create a result list if you first convert each element into a `List` and then use a list operation which concatenates each list, however, there are two problems with this:

- It doesn’t provide the desired “skip each second element (of the original list)” logic; if you look at the tree above, it should become clear, that it is impossible to formulate a correct `op` function which does that in every possible execution scenario
- creating temporary lists and concatenating them is very inefficient

The latter point can be solved by using `collect`, which is a *mutable* reduction, hence, allows you to use mutable lists to which you can add items, however, it does not address the first point, including the desired filter would violate the contract and only work in a sequential execution.

So the solution is to define a `filter` for all elements in the scope of the source list, followed by a mutable reduction to create the result list using `collect`, and, big surprise, that’s exactly what you original code does:

```
… .filter(integer -> integer % 2 == 0).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 9):

You can use the [`Stream.reduce(U identity, BiFunction<U,? super T,U> accumulator, BinaryOperator<U> combiner)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#reduce-U-java.util.function.BiFunction-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-) method, which takes three parameters:

- *identity*: The identity element is both the initial value of the reduction and the default result if there are no elements in the stream. In your case, it will be **an empty list**.
- *accumulator*: The accumulator function takes two parameters: a partial result of the reduction and the next element of the stream (in this example, an integer). It applies a check for modulo 2 and then returns a new partial result.
- *combiner*: It's purpose is to combine the internal temporary collector-accumulators of the stream batches that are being processes in parallel.

For example:

```
BinaryOperator<ArrayList<Integer>> combiner = (x, y) -> { x.addAll(y); return x; };
BiFunction<ArrayList<Integer>, Integer, ArrayList<Integer>> accumulator = (x, y) -> {
    if (y % 2 == 0) {
        x.add(y);
    }
    return x;
};
List<Integer> list = Stream.of(1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10).reduce(new ArrayList<Integer>(),
                                                               accumulator,
                                                               combiner);
System.out.println(list);
```

Note that this solution may not work for parallel Streams. Also, it's way too easier to stick to the `.filter()` approach, so I strongly advice you to do so.

Comment: You are using the wrong reduce method and  `Stream.of(integers)` will give you a stream with a single List element anyway. Not mentioning using `reduce` would result in a complete mess in parallel... In short I don't think using `reduce` is the right tool here. Just stick with `collect(toList())`...

Comment: Try it with `Stream.of(1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10).parallel().reduce(...)` ;-)

Comment: Despite this answer was accepted, it'll give either a wrong result or an exception if the pipeline is run in parallel. You may want to make it clear and edit that.

Comment: Your usage would be correct for `collect` but not for `reduce`.

Comment: @kocko, thanks for your reply. Got an idea about what `reduce()` will do.