# java 8 reduce accumulator return type

Tags: java, dictionary, lambda, java-8, reduce

I need to do a simple traversal over a list of elements, perform some kind of transformation over all of them, and them accumulate all the results in a list.
Something like this:

```
List<GraphEdge> edges = new LinkedList<GraphEdge>();
for (CrawlResult result : crawlResults) {
    edges.addAll(resultToEdges(result));
}
```

This code takes 4 lines, and nothing would make me happier than doing it in one line. Therefore, java 8 streams (map + reduce) for the rescue.

I tried to do it using the following line:

```
List<GraphEdge> edges = graphResults.stream().
        map(res -> resultToEdges(res)).
        reduce(new LinkedList<GraphEdge>(), (list, res) -> list.addAll(res));
```

It doesn't pass compilation because the second of argument of reduce should return a List but it returns a boolean, which is the return type of the addAll method.

Of course, this way would work:

```
List<GraphEdge> edges = graphResults.stream().
                map(res -> resultToEdges(res)).
                reduce(new LinkedList<GraphEdge>(), (list, res) -> 
                { list.addAll(res); return list; });
```

But it's just not as elegant.
Any other way maybe?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using reduce for this kind of things is wrong anyway (see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29072355/how-to-reduce-given-list-by-using-lambda-expression-reduce-method)). You could however, use `flatMap` instead of `map` and collect the final `Stream` into a `List`:

```
List<GraphEdge> edges = graphResults.stream()
        .flatMap(res -> resultToEdges(res).stream())
        .collect(toList()); //or toCollection with a concrete implementation, you can check the docs
```

`flatMap`is simply a map followed by a flattening operation (not surprising), for example:

```
[[1, 2], [3, 4]].flatMap(x -> x.add(5)) //imagine that add returns a list
```

will first apply the mapping:

```
[[1, 2, 5], [3, 4, 5]]
```

and then flatten the lists so that you get:

```
[1, 2, 5, 3, 4, 5]
```

Answer (score 5):

No need to use `reduce`.

```
List<GraphEdge> edges = graphResults.stream().
    flatMap(res -> resultToEdges(res).stream()).
    collect(Collectors.toList());
```

This is assuming `resultToEdges(res)` returns a List (or some other Collection) of `GraphEdge`, which seems to be the case.

Answer (score 3):

Do not use `reduce` for mutable reduction.  It is not just inelegant.  It is wrong and will not work correctly if the stream is ever made parallel.  Either use `flatMap` as other answers suggest, or the 3-argument version of `collect` which is similar to `reduce` but is designed to work with mutable accumulators:

```
List<GraphEdge> edges = graphResults.stream()
    .map(res -> resultToEdges(res))
    .collect(LinkedList::new, LinkedList::addAll, LinkedList::addAll);
```

Answer (score 2):

As already pointed out there is no need to reduce. If you want a `LinkedList` as a returned value you can use:

```
List<GraphEdge> edges = graphResults.stream()
    .flatMap(res -> resultToEdges(res).stream())
    .collect(toCollection(LinkedList::new));
```

Answer (score 0):

In functional languages, there are often immutable Lists and functions that appends/concats and returns a new immutable List. That would have given you a one-liner solution in the lambda. Alas Java doesn't have such methods..